# Svelte/Sapper fetch/this.fetch is not defined in Server side API

Tags: api, svelte, sapper

Here is my question about using Svelte/Sapper

- I have a file in `/src/routes/login.js`
- According to Sapper doc, it will create an API endpoint in `http://<my_domain>/login`, which it does
- Now in `login.js`, I would like to call another API server, assume that it is `http://another_server/auth`
- No matter how I use the `fetch` function: `fetch("http://another_server/auth")`, `this.fetch("http://another_server/auth")`, Svelte responses: `(this.)fetch is not defined`.
- The documentation said that it should be run within `preload()`, so I wrap the fetch under `export async function preload(){}`, it did not work

So my question is: other than using `axios`, can I keep on using `fetch` in server side API request?

Just tested in the template `[slug].json.js` file, when I add the `(this.)fetch` function, it did not compile, same error: `(this.)fetch is not defined`

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install the [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) npm package and use that in your server routes instead of the default `fetch`.

(in /src/routes/login.js):

```js
import fetch from 'node-fetch'
...
// inside your route handler
const response = await fetch('http://another_server/auth') // no error
```

If you are unsure if the code will be executed on the client-side or the server-side (i.e. you're looking for a universal/isomorphic approach) you can use a conditional require:

```js
// inside your route handler
const fetch = process.browser ? window.fetch : require('node-fetch').default
const response = await fetch('http://another_server/auth') // no error
```

But this is probably overkill in your use case since server routes are by definition executed on the server side.